# The Hund's J - Why can this be quantified?

Tags: density-functional-theory, exchange-interaction

I was reading on the the implementation of Hubbard 'U' in Density Functional Theory. The Hubbard 'U' can be thought of as a parameter that accounts for the on-site electron-electron interactions in correlated materials.

Meanwhile, the Hund's J, I'm given to believe is an exchange effect. Many texts mention the 'J' like [this one](https://www.cond-mat.de/events/correl12/manuscripts/cococcioni.pdf). This kind of direct exchange comes from the antisymmetry nature of the many-body electron wavefunction. How can this kind of exchange be quantified by an energy value similar to the Hubbard 'U'? I believe in literature, this 'J' value is usually taken to be less than 20% of the U value. I have not found a conclusive reason for this, but what I am more concerned with, is **how can you possibly quantify such a direct exchange?**